# Anonymous variable in query -- Prolog

Tags: prolog

My program should return

```
City = la
City = phoenix
City = montreal.
```

When I query `weather(City,_,warm).` But it is only returning

```
City = la
```

Here is the content of my prolog .pl file:

```
weather(phoenix,summer,hot).
weather(la,summer,warm).
weather(phoenix,winter,warm).
weather(monteal,winter,warm).
```

I was following a tutorial from 2014, maybe something changed since then?

Comment: maybe use ';' after you get an answer

Comment: Everything looks correct - like @CapelliC said, you get your answers one by one and the semicolon lists the next one.

Comment: @CapelliC was right, just adding ; worked! Thank you CapelliC and lambda.xy.x

Answer (score 0):

@CapelliC was right, needed to add a ; to get all the other answers.